# Is it possible to execute an activity in a fragment of my main activity without affecting the main activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning java/android development and I'm stuck.  I have a main activity and a map clustering activity.  The main activity executes an API call and pulls down lat/lng values for a list of locations.  These lat/lng values are put in an array.  The array is used by another activity to add location markers on a map and cluster them when necessary.  The API call is made when the main activity launches. The map marker/clustering activity is called on a button click. I want the marker/clustering activity to be called on a successful API response without the button click.

I have tried starting the activity after the API response by doing the following:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MarkerClusteringActivity.class));
```

The activity start but the main activity relaunches and I get a wicked loop.  Is it possible to start the map clustering activity inside of a fragment (or some other way) in my main activity that is independent and will NOT reload the main activity?

MapFragment Setup:

```
private void setUpMap() {
((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMapAsync(this);
}
```

I would be glad to provide more info if necessary and any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: The answer is yes. But you don't provide enough code for me to show you how (or for me to understand what the "wicked loop" is.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was in a rush to get out of the office so I just gave a high level overview. I will provide more code. Any examples specific to this would be great also. I'm more of a teach me to fish than a give me a fish kinda guy. 

Answer (score 0):

Seems I've found a fix.  Not sure this is the proper way, but by wrapping the startActivity intent in a method and calling the method at the end of my retrofit response all seems happy.

```
// api call
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<BusinessListings>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<BusinessListings>> call, Response<List<BusinessListings>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                  /**
                   * a lot of stuff happens
                   */
                  //call to method to start new activity in mapfragment with instance state check
                  setMarkers(isRestore); 
}
// method call to set markers/clusters
protected void setMarkers(boolean isRestore) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MarkerClusteringActivity.class));
    }
```